# Why are Gaussian "discriminant" analysis models called so?

Tags: normal-distribution, discriminant-analysis, generative-models

Gaussian discriminant analysis models learn $P(x|y)$ and then apply Bayes rule to evaluate 
$$P(y|x) = \frac{P(x|y)P_{prior}(y)}{\Sigma_{g \in Y} P(x|g) P_{prior}(g) }.$$ Hence, they are generative models. Why then is it called discriminant analysis? If it is because we finally derive a discriminant curve between the classes, then that happens for all generative models.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you mean [LDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) I would say the name, linear discriminant analysis, can be explained historically dating back at least to [Fisher's paper from 1936](http://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/handle/2440/15227), which, to the best of my knowledge, precedes the current terminology and distinction in machine learning between a discriminative and a generative model. Not that Fisher called it linear discriminant analysis directly, but he did explicitly ask for a linear function for discrimination. As a curious side remark, Fisher considered discrimination for the famous Iris data set in the paper.

Fisher did, by the way, not present the linear method for discrimination in terms of a generative model. He sought a linear combination (for two classes) that maximizes the ratio of the *between-group variance* to the *within-group variance*, which does not require a normality assumption. Details, and how it relates to LDA as a Bayes rule for a generative model, can be found in Chapter 3 in Brian Ripley's book "Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks".

Answer (score 4):

It is simple, in case you have two classes $(Y=0 , Y=1)$, the GDA makes use of this assumption:

1. $P(X|Y=0) \sim  \mathcal{N}(\mu_0,\Sigma_0) $
2. $P(X|Y=1) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1,\Sigma_1)$
3. $P(Y=1)=1-P(Y=0)=\Phi$

And then gets the parameters $(\mu_0,\Sigma_0,\mu_1,\Sigma_1,\Phi)$ using maximum likelihood estimation.

So it's **Gaussian** because it uses a gaussian assumption for the intra-goup distribution (you may want to use uniform instead for ex) and **discriminant** because it aims to separate data into groups.

You can find more info [here](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/aimlcs229/cs229-notes2.pdf).