# LDA for feature extraction with more than one feature

Tags: feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I know that LDA (linear discriminant analysis) is a way for feature extraction, but the dimension of LDA is one less than number of classes in problem (in two classes, the dimension of the result space is 1), so the number of features by LDA is always 1 (in 2 classes case). Is there anyway to extract more than 1 feature with LDA? (When we use PCA we can select n top eigen-vectors for more than 1 feature, but I couldn't find similar way for LDA)

Comment: No, you cannot extract more than min(p,g-1) where p is the number of input features ang g is the number of groups. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/169436/3277, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/190821/3277

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks, so there is no extension on LDA for this purpose?

Comment: LDA is different from PCA substantially, LDA is "supervised", PCA is not. LDA is close akin to canonical correlations ([see](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65692/3277) comparison with PCA). But what do you want specifically? Under LDA assumptions hold 1 discriminant will _suffice_ to predict class membership (see link 2) in 2-class situation. Why do you want any more latent variables, what for?

Comment: @ttnphns I need more than one feature for classification and the output of LDA is not enough. I though there may be other approaches that consider labels and also extract more than one feature.

Comment: Once again, please: read my answer in the 2nd link. Citing: "Then q=g−1=2 independent dimensions will suffice to predict the class membership as precisely as formerly". If LDA assumptions hold, all the discriminants are _enough_ to classify optimally.