# Linear discriminant analysis posterior not giving expected values in R

Tags: r, probability, classification, linear-model, posterior

I have two normal distributions fg and bg with mean (mu) and standard deviations (sd) as follows:

```
set.seed(100)
fg = rnorm(10000, mean=11.00, sd=3.77)
bg = rnorm(10000, mean=-0.508, sd=1.04)
```

[image: disros]

If I fit an LDA model like this:

```
library(MASS)
mydata = data.frame(label = c(rep(1, 10000), rep(0,10000)), 
                    score = c(fg, bg))

fit = lda(label~score, data=mydata)
```

And try and to predict some new values:

```
newvals = seq(-7, 25, 0.1)
pred = predict(fit, data.frame(score=newvals))

# Plot posterior
matplot(newvals, pred$posterior, type='l', col=c('red', 'blue'), lty=1)
```

I get posteriors which look like this:

[image]

At a value of 5, the posterior for belonging to either class is 0.5, but looking at the density plots above, you can see that at 5 it almost always belongs to the fg distribution. I would expect the posterior to be 0.5 closer to 2.5-3, where both density curves cross eachother.

Can anyone please explain why the lda posteriors are behaving this way - or if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to Flounderer nice answer, read also http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71571/3277, http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/190821/3277. QDA is the appropriate choice, but LDA could be used as well (read how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because LDA assumes that each of the two classes follows a normal distribution with (possibly) different means, but the same variance. In your case, the class distributions have different variances. In a sense, LDA is approximating the graph in your first figure by a graph in which the red and blue humps have the same width, so you shouldn't expect it to be a very good approximation. You could try QDA instead.

In fact, if you replace `lda` in your code by `qda` you get this picture, which is more like what you expected!

[image]

Comment: Thanks! qda does give me what I expect, minus the fact that at around -5 to -7 the posterior drops for the bg and is and jumps for the fg, whereas I would expect them to remain at 1 (for the bg) and 0 (for the fg), as it did with lda. Is there any reason this is happening? / any way to circumvent this or any other approach I can take?

Comment: The blue curve is actually above the red curve if you go far enough to the left, e.g. `dnorm(-6, mean=11.00, sd=3.77) - dnorm(-6, mean=-0.508, sd=1.04)` is positive, so you will need to choose different functions if you don't want this to happen.