# Is Linear Discriminate Analysis (LDA) and Fisher Discriminant Analysis (FDA) same meaning?

Tags: linear-model, discriminant-analysis

Is Linear Discriminate Analysis (LDA) and Fisher Discriminant Analysis (FDA) same meaning?

And also Fisher Criterion (FC)?

Do these three terms interchangeably, having the same meaning?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71489/three-versions-of-discriminant-analysis-differences-and-how-to-use-them

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, not, the link is different. Still unclear

Comment: @aan: Could you edit your question to focus on any aspects that are unaddressed in the answers to the duplicates? Else you'd be likely to get much the same answers.